# Oracle SQL Syntax: With clause

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, gsp

I'm currently using the Java Version of [General SQL Parser for Oracle](http://www.sqlparser.com/) for some relatively complex Oracle SQL Queries.

As in my case I have no access to any Oracle DB but only have the SQL statements in a file I encounter some statements where the parser fails, one particular boils down to following.

```
select id from (
with foo as (
    select bar from sometable
)
select *
from foo
)
```

The with clause can be parsed without problem, if not nested.

```
with foo as (
    select bar from sometable
)
select *
from foo
```

So do I have a bug in the parser or in the statement?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement is valid, so I guess the parser just can't handle it.

To be sure, try running the SQL in SQL Plus.

Comment: Can we use SQL Plus without a Oracle DB, just to test if some SQL statements are valid?

Comment: No you need the DBMS to parse the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfectly valid statement in Oracle (I just tried it).
But it might not be valid ANSI SQL and that might be the reason why the parser doesn't understand it.